# Using foreach function issue in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code which permits me to get some ids

```
$sql_id_att="SELECT DISTINCT att_id FROM agenzia_pdv WHERE id_ag='$id_ag'";
$resultuserid_att=mysql_query($sql_id_att) or die(mysql_error());
while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($resultuserid_att, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

    $id_att=$rows['att_id'];
    echo $id_att;

}
```

And this one which i use to do the foreach function

```
foreach ($id_att as $attivita_id) {

    ?>
<form action="lista_attivita_ag_modifica.php?&id=<?php echo $attivita_id ; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="hidden" name="form_secret" id="form_secret" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['FORM_SECRET'];?>" />
<input type="submit" name="edit" value="<?php echo $row['attivita_da_promuovere']; ?>" />
</form>

<?php
    }
```

What am i doing wrong here?
It says:
 Invalid argument supplied for foreach
But when i print the $id_att it works fine!
Thanks

I have this two arrays:

```
 $attivita_name[]=$rows['attivita_da_promuovere'
 $id_att[]=$rows['att_id'];
```

How can i print their contents using foreach, i mean i need to print :

```
$attivita_name[0]| $id_att[0]
$attivita_name[1]| $id_att[1]
$attivita_name[2]| $id_att[2]
```

Comment: The first argument of foreach has to be an `Traversable `, usually an `array`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to make `$id_att` as array

```
$sql_id_att="SELECT DISTINCT att_id FROM agenzia_pdv WHERE id_ag='$id_ag'";
$resultuserid_att=mysql_query($sql_id_att) or die(mysql_error());

$id_att = array();
$attivita_name = array();
while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($resultuserid_att, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $attivita_name[]=$rows['attivita_da_promuovere'];
    $id_att[]=$rows['att_id'];
    echo $rows['att_id'];
}

// then you can iterate $id_att using foreach loop here
$result_str = "";
for($i=0 ; $i < count($id_att) ; $i++) {
    $result_str .= $attivita_name[$i] . "|" . $id_att[$i] . "\n";
}
echo $result_str;
```

Comment: Thank you, this works fine :)
Please, i have another question regarding this, i'm updating my question if possible take a look...